# Grid of UIButtons using 2D Array

Tags: swift, xcode, multidimensional-array, uibutton

As a little project, I want to make my own version of [this little game](https://www.crazygames.com/game/catch-the-dot).

I need a grid of UIButtons for this, so I thought about solving this using an 2D-Array.
This is all I got so far:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var btnArr: [[UIButton]] = [] // CREATE A 2D-ARRAY OF UIBUTTONS

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buildBoard()
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button " + sender.title(for: .normal)! + " tapped")
    }
    
    func buildBoard(){
        let btnSize = 40
        var x = 1
        var xPos = 0
          while(x<10){
            var y = 5
            var yPos = 0
             while(y<14){
                  let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: x*btnSize, y: y*btnSize, width: btnSize, height: btnSize))
                  button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
                  button.clipsToBounds = true
                  button.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                  button.setTitle(String(xPos) + ", " + String(yPos), for: .normal)
                  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
                  self.view.addSubview(button)
                  btnArr[xPos][yPos] = button  // ADD THE BUTTONS TO THE 2D-ARRAY
                  y+=1
                yPos+=1
              }
            xPos+=1
              x+=1
          }
    }
}
```

The thing with x and xPos is not that beautiful but I wanted to center the grid and count the buttons starting from (0,0) and not (1,5).

**My problem:**

I want to add the created buttons to my array "btnArr" but it gives me a *Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range*. I found the problem as I cannot just add buttons to my array like this, because its empty. But I have no clue how to make this work...

And is it possible to make the needed offset as seen in the link using this 2d-array-implementation?

Thanks for any help!!!

And if you want to join my project write me :)

Comment: You should use `append` when adding elements to an array. Please do some basic research when starting a new project, you can read about arrays [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) for instance. Maybe you should also read up on loops, check the first link

Answer (score 0):

You can take collection view instead and keep your 2D array in sync with cells of collection view.

You can create custom cell of collection view with UIButton object inside it, add tags for each button in cell and add target selector on button click.

This will reduce your code and improve it's maintainability.